# Two MySQLs after updating to El Capitan

Tags: mysql

I installed MySQL with `brew install mysql` in Yosemite and working fine. After updating from Yosemite to El Capitan, I uninstalled mysql and installed it again. Now I am not able to connect to MySQL. But I am able to connect with SequelPro. I am not sure why. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are phpMyAdmin and SequelPro using the same connection type?

If you aren't sure, find out if SequelPro is using TCP/IP or Local Socket/Pipes, and then adjust your phpMyAdmin settings to use the same connection type.